# Consuming WCF Service with external library

Tags: c#, wcf

This is solved. The sollution can be found here: [Unable to initialize member through Constructor in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752947/unable-to-initialize-member-through-constructor-in-wcf/33753414#33753414)

In additon to that answer, I had to add bindings to the client. Code:

```
        BasicHttpBinding binding1 = new BasicHttpBinding();
        var cf = new ChannelFactory<IWebService>(binding1,webServiceURL);
        var channel = cf.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(webServiceURL));
        return channel;
```

Original Question: 
I have an ASP.Net Webapplication which consumes a WCF Service.

Since both applications are using some shared libraries, I configured the Service to "reuse types in referenced assemblies".

However, If I configure the Service like this, I cannot find the Namespace the service is in, so I cannot create an instance of the class.

If I configure the Service not to reuse types in referenced assemblies, I can find the namespace & I can also create an instance. However, the Service uses automatically created objects that are copies of the objects I want to use.

That means, I would have to either :

- Manually change the reference.cs file so it uses the correct objects. Since I will have to update the service in the future, this is not a good way to go. I would have to fix the reference.cs file every time I update the service, since the class is being regenerated.
- Translate my objects to the automatically generated objects whenever I use the service.

That's also not a good idea since I would have to update the translations every time an object changes.

**Steps I have taken:**

- Updated from Visual Studio 2013 to 2015 since I thought (and still think) it might be a bug within VS
- Configure the service to explicitly only reuse the shared libraries. The result is the same than reusing all libraries.
- Researched stackoverflow :
  [WP7, How to use a service reference after adding it to Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262563/wp7-how-to-use-a-service-reference-after-adding-it-to-visual-studio-2010) If I click "View in object browser", the service seems to be within my top level Namespace.

Comment: Check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752947/unable-to-initialize-member-through-constructor-in-wcf/33753414#33753414 It might be helpful.

Comment: Do you include the wcf service project in the client solution?

Comment: @RossBush yes, all Projects (WebApplication, Service and shared libraries) are in the same sollution

Comment: @JanneMatikainen that worked. Thank you! I cannot mark your comment as answer. I'll update my question with your sollution...

However, I had to add binding to the client... Working code:             BasicHttpBinding binding1 = new BasicHttpBinding();
            var cf = new ChannelFactory<IWebService>(binding1,webServiceURL);
            var channel = cf.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(webServiceURL));
            return channel;